# Setting a dynamic type's docstring in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am dynamically creating some classes and I want them to have different docstrings.  I have:

```
def make_class(class_docstring):
    class X:
        pass
    X.__doc__ = class_docstring
    return X
```

That didn't work because docstrings are read-only.  Then, I tried:

```
def make_class(class_name, class_docstring):
    class X:
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

    d = {'__doc__': class_docstring}
    d.update(X.__dict__)
    return type(class_name, (), d)

ClassName = make_class(
    'ClassName',
    """
    Some docstring...
    """)
```

which worked until it had to call `super`.

What is the correct way to dynamically set the docstring attribute?

Comment: Your first approach works perfectly fine.  Why do you think doc strings are read-only?  They aren't.

Comment: That is, in Python 2.x at least.  Are you using Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the docstring inside the class.

```
>>> def make_class(class_docstring):
...     class X:
...         __doc__ = class_docstring
...     return X
...
>>> x = make_class('test doc')
>>> x
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> xx = x()
>>> xx.__doc__
'test doc'
```

I'm not sure why your 2nd attempt is failing.

Comment: The second attempt fails because the call to `super()` is binding to the type `X` (it's being translated to `super(X)`) and then the method is being copied to the dynamically-created type, which doesn't have `X` in its `__mro__`.

Comment: Would it be okay for me to use: `globals()[class_name] = X` instead of `return X` so that I can just write `make_class('name', 'docstring')` instead of `name = make_class(…`?

Comment: @NeilG: It might work, but injecting things into globals is almost always bad practice. It's much clearer to use `name = ...` .